# Iterating through a list/dictionary over and over again with a timestep value

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary:

```
{0: [[(4, 1), (1, 4)], [(2, 3), (3, 2)], [(4, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4)]]}
```

How do I iterate through the nested list values `[(4, 1), (1, 4)], [(2, 3), (3, 2)]...` over and over again depending on a initiated count value?

For example: initiated_count_value = 0 would refer to `[(4, 1), (1, 4)]`, while initiated_count_value = 3 would refer to `[(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4)]` but then as the count changes by going up the values of the nested list are still referenced.

For example: initiated count value of 4 would refer back again to `[(4, 1), (1, 4)]`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are looking for `[p[i] for p in dct[0]]`?  Or, if you want wraparound, `[p[i%len(p)] for p in dct[0]]`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is the dictionary relevant to the problem? It seems like the question is entirely about what to do with the nested list. In that case, it doesn't matter where the nested list comes from, only *what it contains*. Please read [mre].

Comment: I dont get why you talk about iterating over it while all your requested outputs consists of only 1 element. In any case, I think you should look into the modulo operator `%` with the length of your list, so count `4` would refer to item `0` and so on.

Comment: @TitouanL hello, sorry I am only learning python and have now realised my wording was wrong. It's not really about iterating over the list more like i have a value, count value which can index any item in the list again and again so 4 would index that the first value of the list

Comment: Ok, I understand what you want, did you manage to get it working from @ljmc's solution (by transforming the loop a bit) or do you still need a more specific answer ?

Answer (score 0):

To loop the overall list index back to the beginning, you can use the [`%` modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=modulo#operator.mod).

```
d = {
    0: [
        [(4, 1), (1, 4)],
        [(2, 3), (3, 2)],
        [(4, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 1)],
        [(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4)],
    ]
}

for initiated_count_value in range(6):
    di = initiated_count_value % len(d[0])
    print(d[0][di])
    
--
[(4, 1), (1, 4)]
[(2, 3), (3, 2)]
[(4, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 1)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4)]
[(4, 1), (1, 4)]
[(2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator which took an initial index and then iterated through the list starting at that index and wrapping around:

```py
def get_list(icv):
    l = len(dct[0])
    while True:
        yield dct[0][icv % l]
        icv += 1
```

You could then do something like:

```py
initiated_count_value = 3
for l in get_list(initiated_count_value):
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4)]
[(4, 1), (1, 4)]
[(2, 3), (3, 2)]
[(4, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 1)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4)]
[(4, 1), (1, 4)]
[(2, 3), (3, 2)]
[(4, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 1)]
...
```

If you don't want the loop to run forever, replace the `while True` in `get_list` with something like a `for i in range(100)` or similar.